# Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' --Flutter - RealtimeDatabase -

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get the information of the latest added to the database.
I have seen on the internet that one way to get the information is this,

```
await _lastKeyRef.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.value != null) {
    Map<dynamic, dynamic> _values = snapshot.value;
    _values.forEach((key, value) { 
       .... code ...
    });
 { 
{
```

but it gives me an error.

I leave the code to see if someone can help me.

[Picture of Realtime Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGGpj.png)

```
final String _uid = SupermarketApp.sharedPreferences.getString(SupermarketApp.userUID);
final _turnRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance
      .reference()
      .child('cod')
      .child('service');


Future<void> createTurn() async {
    var _lastKeyRef = _turnRef.orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
    DateTime _timeNow = new DateTime.now();
    int _lastNumber;
    int _setNumber;

    await _lastKeyRef.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.value != null) {
        Map<dynamic, dynamic> _values = snapshot.value;
        _values.forEach((key, value) {
          _lastNumber = int.parse(key) + 1;
          _setNumber = value['num'] + 1;
        });

        if (_setNumber > 99) _setNumber = 1;

        _turnRef.child(_lastNumber.toString()).set(
            {'app': true, 'user_id': _uid, 'date': _timeNow.toString(), 'num': _setNumber});
      } else {
        _turnRef
            .child('1')
            .set({'app': true, 'user_id': _uid, 'date': _timeNow.toString(), 'num': 1});
      }
    });
}
```

[Picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiO8D.png)

Thank you.

**--Edit--**

The code is good. The Exeption was due to having a "1" as a key in realtime database. I dont know why, but i change the key name and it works.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because `snapshot.value` returns a List but you're reading it as a `Map`.

Updating the code to the one below should fix this:

```dart
    List<dynamic> _values = snapshot.value;
    _values.forEach((element) {
    int key = _values.indexOf(element)l
    _lastNumber = int.parse(key) + 1;
    _setNumber = element['num'] + 1;
    });
```

Comment: This doenst work. I cant use '.key' and '.value', i have to use '.keys' and '.values', and give me this error: '[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'keys' was called on null.'

Comment: Hi, can you add the code for the change you added?

Comment: Also, checkout the code update I added and see if it works.

Comment: The code is good. The Exeption was due to having a "1" as a key in realtime database. I dont know why, but i change the key name and it works.